# Why it reported The metadata deploy operation failed?

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx

First, I used the below command to do a apex class test -

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --checkonly --testlevel RunSpecifiedTests --runtests ProvisioningQuestionDelete_CC_Test  --zipfile b.zip
```

and then i used the following command to get the result. But why it reported deploy operation failed please?

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy:report
```

Deployment finished in 204000ms

```
=== Result
Status:  Failed
jobid:  0Af0R00000RijoHSAR
Completed:  2019-05-27T05:54:49.000Z
Component errors:  0
Components checked:  9
Components total:  9
Tests errors:  0
Tests completed:  9
Tests total:  9
Check only: true

=== Test Success [9]
NAME                      METHOD
────────────────────────  ───────────────────────────
ProvisioningForm_CC_Test  testEmptyProducts
ProvisioningForm_CC_Test  testFillProducts
ProvisioningForm_CC_Test  testFilterProducts
ProvisioningForm_CC_Test  testFilterProducts1
ProvisioningForm_CC_Test  testFilterProducts2
ProvisioningForm_CC_Test  testFormForOrder
ProvisioningForm_CC_Test  testGetParentAnswersAsList
ProvisioningForm_CC_Test  testGetQuestionValuesAsList
ProvisioningForm_CC_Test  testListContainsOneOfList

=== Apex Code Coverage
NAME                 % COVERED  UNCOVERED LINES
───────────────────  ─────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
ProvisioningForm_CC  **86%**        14,16,29,50,51,74,86,94,95,97,98,99,102,121,122,128,155,159,247,262,266,267,268,269,270,307,308,310,311,312,348,349,350,351,352,411,414,417,420,423,533,570,586,597,600,715,722,758,760,762,764,802,827,828,829,830,851,892,899,912,1009,1011,1013,1014,1015,1016,1038,1039,1040,1041,1042,1043,1044,1045,1046,1047,1048,1049,1050,1051,1053,1060

Total Test Time:  18417.0
```

ERROR running force:mdapi:deploy:report:  The metadata deploy operation failed.

Comment: Since what you're deploying is a package you can go to "Setup ---> Deployment settings" and gather more information there about what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by Mariano Hernandez, to know what did go wrong, you'll need the visual feedback of deployment details, which is available in the `Deployment Status` page, at Salesforce Setup section. It will have the log details you need. You can use the link below as a shortcut:

https://<YOUR_ORG_NAME_HERE>.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/DeployStatus/home

[image]